# Need a help on form post/submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need your helps on little bit hack of javascript.

From today morning I am working on one simple hack That would Post a form multiple time.

See, this image.

[image]

This is simple form, Now what i want is to post this form multiple time.

as form has no identifier, this query post form for single time.

```
$("input[type='submit']").closest("form").submit();
```

but, i want it in loop to execute for several times.

One more thing, after each post page redirected to another page so, I couldn't make it in loop post/submit.

This is challenge for me from someone, any help (like a flow or loop related idea) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the `method` of form : is it POST or GET ?

Comment: it's a post., you can see form image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax call :

```
const $form = $("input[type='submit']").closest("form"); // Save the form element

const params = $form.serialize(); // get the values of form inputs in JSON object
const maxCalls = 20;

let counter = 0;
function submitForm() {
   console.info('callº', counter + 1);
   $.post('mailSender.php', params, function(response) {
       counter++;
       if (counter <= maxCalls)
          submitForm() // Sync call  Call (n+1) starts when Call(n)  finishes
        else {console.log('We are done! ✅')}

   });
}


submitForm(); // This will submit form 20 times without refreshing page.
```

Comment: dude you are awesome, let me try.

Comment: I got TypeError, form post first time correctly, but second time "TypeError: invalid assignment to const `counter' " this error ocured.

Comment: do you need snap?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136622/discussion-between-bharat-and-abdennour-toumi).